# show multiple rows words on <textarea> but single row in <div>

Tags: css

Let's say I typed in a `<textarea>`:
**I

Love

You**

Then I save it to phpMyAdmin database. Then I use MySQL to retrieve it from database and display it onto a `<div>`. Now the output that show in the `<div>` is :
**I Love You**

How do I make the `<div>` show exactly like the database field and textarea which has multiple rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text is stored exactly as it was entered into the `<textarea>` (i.e. it still contains the newline; check this by viewing the source of your page), you can use the CSS property `white-space: pre` on your `<div>`.

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bXmjT/); note how the content of both `<div>` tags are the same, but produce different output, due to the use of the `white-space` property in the second `<div>`.

Comment: simple and nice. Perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Replace line returns with `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If the textarea supports use of HTML tags (similar to the Stack Overflow answer box that I'm typing in now), then you could type:

```
I <br>
love <br>
you
```

and it would render in the way you want it to.